# Можно ли получить определенные элементы с блока по классу в JS?

Tags: javascript

Допустим в одном блоке есть несколько блоков с классом "q", а так же есть есть второй блок, в котором тоже есть блоки с классом "q". Можно ли как-то получить все элементы в с классом "q" но только с первого блока.

```html
<div class= "random_class">
  <div class = "q">1</div>
  <div class = "q">2</div>
  <div class = "q">3</div>
  <div class = "q">4</div>
</div>

<div class= "random_class_1">
  <div class = "q">5</div>
  <div class = "q">6</div>
  <div class = "q">7</div>
  <div class = "q">8</div>
</div>
```

Можно ли это как то сделать? или это невозможно? Я начинающий программист, много не знаю, заранее спасибо за ответ.

document.querySelectorAll(.random_class) не подойдет, этот класс может изменяться.

Comment: Можно у них родительский класс различен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берём все элементы, определяем их родителя и составляем "список" родителей, после этого можем от списка родителей обращаться к его дочерним элементам.

```js
let elem = document.querySelectorAll('.q'), // Все элементы с неизвестным родителем
    parents = []; // Список родителей

[...elem].map(e => { // Проходим по всем элементам
  let firstClass = e.parentElement; // Получаем родителя
  if(!parents.includes(firstClass)) // Если родителя нет в списке..
    parents.push(firstClass); // .. то добавляем его
});

console.info(parents); // Видим список всех родителей

let elems = parents[0].querySelectorAll('.q'); // Возьмём элементы первого родителя из списка

[...elems].map(e => e.style.color = 'red'); // Установим этим элементам красный цвет текста.
```

```html
<div class="random_class">
  <div class="q">1</div>
  <div class="q">2</div>
  <div class="q">3</div>
  <div class="q">4</div>
</div>

<div class="random_class_1">
  <div class="q">5</div>
  <div class="q">6</div>
  <div class="q">7</div>
  <div class="q">8</div>
</div>
```

---

Ещё вариант.

Вы сказали, что в зависимости от количества блоков - класс изменяется и привели пример `random_class` и `random_class_1`, если `random_class` присутствует всегда, добавляя только число, вы можете обращаться к элементам `.q` через `document.querySelectorAll('[class^="random_class"] .q')`, таким образом используя что-то типо регулярки, при котором будут браться элементы у которых родитель будет иметь [атрибут `class` начинающийся с `random_class`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/attr3).

Answer (score 1):

так поробуйте

```js
var fiterElements = '.random_class .q'; // меняйте как хотите
var inner = document.querySelectorAll(fiterElements);

console.log(inner);
```

```html
<div class= "random_class">
  <div class = "q">1</div>
  <div class = "q">2</div>
  <div class = "q">3</div>
  <div class = "q">4</div>
</div>

<div class= "random_class_1">
  <div class = "q">5</div>
  <div class = "q">6</div>
  <div class = "q">7</div>
  <div class = "q">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: random_class он неизвестный, в зависимости от количества контента в блоке, класс изменяется, а контент может добавляться. В общем не получится. Никак по другому не получится?

Comment: В общем, получется общее. А если существует какая-то логика то можно получить конкретный результат. Первый, последний, пятый, первый который похож на .... Как говорил Архимед Точку опоры

Comment: Поймите, "дай мне то незнаю что" не работает на конкретный случай, он работает в общем "ВЕРНЕТ ВСЁ" :)

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет?

```js
let qBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('div:first-child>.q');

qBlocks.forEach((block) => {
  console.log(block.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="random_class">
  <div class="q">1</div>
  <div class="q">2</div>
  <div class="q">3</div>
  <div class="q">4</div>
</div>

<div class="random_class_1">
  <div class="q">5</div>
  <div class="q">6</div>
  <div class="q">7</div>
  <div class="q">8</div>
</div>
```